# Angularjs not working in http or ajax loaded php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I tried to load php file to my main page using angularjs http function or ajax load function and it is working fine. when I loaded php file using both method, main page Angularjs cods are not working for loaded php file. I used xeditable framework also but it is also not working in loaded page. I know jQuery code can use live keywords to work fine. How to solve this problem for Angularjs?

Comment: could you provide your code snippets?, that will help us find out.

Comment: This is not a question and it misses code snippets.